# How to change a specific inline style from a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically, I am simply trying to change an inline style from a HTML element that I have.

For example, my `h1` tag:

```
<h1 id="headerTop" style="width: 500px; max-width:none; top: 234px;">Something goes here</h1>
```

I am trying to change `top` to something different after my page is loaded. Therefore, I am trying to use this piece of Javascript just before the closing of my `body` tag:

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("headerTop").style.top = "470px";
</script>
```

Although, this makes no change.

I am trying to do this since my `h1` element originally has no `top` attribute within my page source UNTIL it is loaded inside a browser. It is then given `top: 234px;`. Can't seem to find out why. I am using a purchased template from another site, so there must be something somewhere that is causing this to happen. The `top` attribute is DEFINITELY being added inline.

Comment: If it is not in the initially loaded HTML code, then it will most likely be added by some kind of script (I assume you look at the element in some kind of DOM inspector and see the top value there?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery way would be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#headerTop').css({
    'top': '470px'
  });
})
</script>
```

This will change the css property top to 470px on the element with an id of "headerTop"

If you need to delay the javascript exection, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#headerTop').css({
      'top': '470px'
    });
  },1000)
})
</script>
```

This causes the execution to be delayed by 1 second.
Probably not ideal, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: Not ideal... But it worked! I can live with this, mainly since I have a load animation that occurs while the main parts of the site are loading such as images. Great, thanks for your help!

Comment: Although, since my website works with AJAX, when the home page is revisited, the `h1` is back into its original position. Therefore, this is only a temporary fix.

Comment: Good luck in finding a more permanent solution. Try finding the culprit and remove it from it from the root.

Answer (score 4):

**first add position absolute or relative to see changes**

**in javascript**

**html**

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

**js**

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
 document.getElementById("headerTop").style.top = "470px";
}
</script>
```

**in jquery** no need to add in **body** tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#headerTop").css("top","470px");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no change :(

Comment: make position absolute or relative to see effect

Comment: Changing between `absolute` and `relative` make no difference

Comment: now remove myfunction in body it will work because you add jquery code so need to add myfunction i have also mention in my answer it

Comment: As you can see, I got it working with @netbrain code. Although, when you visit a different page, then revisit the home page, the image is back to its original position. I uploaded the updated copy of index.html.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `position:relative`

You can set top,left, right, bottom with positioned elements

So either set `position:relative` or `absolute` according to your need.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgHBy/1/)

**Update**

As you are saying you already applied `position:relative`, then try writting script just before `</body>` and see what happens.

Comment: It already has `position: relative;` within my style-sheet. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Well your URL is having an error `myfunction()` is not defined. Remove it from body `onload()`

Comment: Whoops, forgot to remove that earlier. Thanks. I need to somehow go into the DOM with Firebug or something to find out what script is actually making these calculations on positioning the H1

Answer (score 1):

The template probably hooks into the document onload function, or a jquery ready function, and does some calculation and adds the property.

The problem with overriding this is that you have to make sure you are doing it AFTER the template has done its work, otherwise the template will just overwrite your change.

By hooking into onload, you will probably be too early.

What about changing the template javascript code directly?

You could try to use the jquery ready function, but it depends if this is registered before or after the template if it will have any affect. document.ready() callbacks are called in the order they were registered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#headerTop").css("top","470px");
});
```

Also, to position elements using top/left/right/bottom, you need to create a positioning context. This is easily done by adding set `position:relative` to your h1 element.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately :( But I think your suggestions are correct. I will need to find the source of what is doing the calculations and slightly edit them.

Answer (score 0):

using Jquery you can directly use css to set inline style
$('#headerTop').css('top','470px');

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain if this is what might work, for this issue, but it solved my issue so I'm posting it to maybe help someone else.
I wanted to use the display none so I would not take up room on the page , but display visible so my parent div would grow in height instead on the content spilling out on bottom so I used this javascript , hope it can help someone else.

```
function changeStyle7(){
    // Selecting element
    var elem = document.getElementById('change');    
   if( elem.className == "dropdown-content1"){elem.className = "dropdown-content";}      
else {elem.className = "dropdown-content1";}
}
```

Then just added the dropdown_content1 section to my style sheet with the visibility :visible  instead of display:none now my parent div grows when i open the hidden div
and of course add the onclick changeStyle7() to my button.
almost forgot the html.

```
<div class="dropdown-content"id="change"> some stuff</div>

<style>
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content1 {
  visibility: visible;
  position: relitive;
</style>
```